# Web Services for Desktop App

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, glassfish, desktop-application

I need opinion of experts.

I  have GUI Desktop App, it's connected with external DB and everything works fine.I use GlassFish Server 4.1. 
I dont use any framefork such as Hibernate,XML,Spring. It's simple Desktop App with class Repository and methods.

My question is...

Is it possible to create Web Service for Java Desktop App? and what is the best way to do it cause I dont have option to create new Web Service in Java Application, only have that option when I start new web project. (Im using NetBeans).

I dont know how to create wsdl from existing class.

Here is my code my Repository class with few methods so u can see my point.

```
public class Repository {

    static private Connection conn;

    static private PreparedStatement st;
    static private PreparedStatement st2;
    static private ResultSet rs ;

public static List<Gender> getGender()  {

     List<Gender> res = new ArrayList<>();
      try{ 
            conn = Database.getConnection();
            st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from  pitanja.gender");
            rs = st.executeQuery();
            res = new ArrayList<>(); 
        while(rs.next()){
            Gender g = new Gender();
            g.id = rs.getInt("id");
            g.tip = rs.getString("tip");
            res.add(g);}}
        catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){}
        return res;
}
public static void addUser(int sifra,Korisnik k)  {  

    try{
    conn = Database.getConnection();
    st = conn.prepareStatement("insert into korisnik(ime,prezime,br_index,gender) values (?,?,?,?)");  
    st.setString(1,k.ime);
    st.setString(2,k.prezime);
    st.setInt(3, k.br_index);
    st.setInt(4, k.gender.id);

    st.execute();}//izvrsi
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){}
}

public static boolean UserValidation(int sifra) { 

    boolean unique=true;
    try{
    conn = Database.getConnection();
    st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from korisnik  where br_index = ? ");
    st.setInt(1, sifra);

    rs = st.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()){   
    unique= false;}}
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){}
return unique;
 }
```

So as u can see this is just a part of my Repository methods, so I would like to hide my logic, I would like to create SOAP Web Service and after I create SOAP I will easly create Web Service Client and implement wsdl from remote machine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have a class just for gender??

Comment: yes it's Entity class, I combine with comboBox, so when user creates profile he can choose either men/woman .

Comment: If you got a web service, you do not have to write a desktop app as there are lot of available free tools where you call the webservices such as `soapui`

Comment: I dont have web service, I have to create  one!?